# design option of xml file not showing in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I cannot see the "Design" option when I open my xml file in android studio. In some tutorials, I have seen it to be in the bottom left of the text of the xml file beside the "text" option, but in my case, it is not there! the "text" option is there but not the "design". Instead, there's an option called "Merged Manifest". please help.

[image]

Comment: The manifest page doesn't have a design option since it's not a "view", it contains app's metadata. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click on res folder(above gradle file)--> layout--> xmlfile.xml.

In layout folder, you make the design for your activities,

In manifest.xml file, you declare each activity's name. Manifest.xml is not a design page